# dm-script: Is there a command to save as TIFF8 and TIFF24?

Tags: format, save, tiff, dm-script

dm-script: Is there a command to save as TIFF8 and TIFF24? I would like to insert the possibility in a script.

Comment: Not sure why it was down-voted. A perfectly legit question to be asked here!

Answer (score 1):

Script access to import/export is identical to what you get via the menu and depends on your installation (All code is in `ImportExport Plug-in.dll`)

To script-access exactly this functionality, you have to save the `ImageDocument` associated with the image, and you have to provide the *IOhandler* which should do it.

The actual data type written then depends on:

- the data type of the image you want to write
- the handler and how it "converts" the image, i.e. some filetypes can handle different data depth, others can't and do the conversion.
- whether the "view" image or the "raw data" image is saved.

As a script this goes like this:

```
Image img := IntegerImage( "Test S-Int32 ", 4, 1,  512, 512 )
img =  1000 * sin( Pi() * itheta ) % icol
number saveType = 1         // 0 = Save VIEW; 1 = Save DATA; 2 = (Default) Try VIEW else DATA
ImageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
string fileName = "C:\\TestImage(" + saveType + ")"
doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile( "TIFF Format", fileName, saveType )
```

Note that I've used `TIFF Format` as a string to specify the handler. The available names are those you can see in the drop-down when you "Save As" an image via the menu. For example, I currently get:

[image]

Use the strings before the `(file type)` part of the entry and use it case-sensitive.